# Why is my ajax form not submitting data?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have my ajax form codes in place. That is; HTML, JS, & PHP but somehow I do not know why it is not working. I am sure there are some mistakes but I don't know where and how. Below is my code.

Here is the form web page: [EXAMPLE](http://placmedia.com/packages/starter-package.html)  But somehow the form isn't submitting ( it is supposed to be ajax but nothing happens when i click the submit button)

I need a quick fix to this and something I can use as a preference!

```
// -----------------------------------------------------
// ----------------    CONTACT FORM    -----------------
// -----------------------------------------------------
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    reddy_contact_form();
    reddy_anchor();

});


function reddy_contact_form(){

    "use strict";

    jQuery(".contact_form #send_message").on('click', function(){

        var fname       = jQuery(".contact_form #fname").val();
        var email       = jQuery(".contact_form #email").val();
        var bname       = jQuery(".contact_form #bname").val();
        var number      = jQuery(".contact_form #number").val();
        var package     = jQuery(".contact_form #package").val();
        var domain      = jQuery(".contact_form #domain").val();
        var logo        = jQuery(".contact_form #logo").val();
        var img         = jQuery(".contact_form #img").val();
        var rcont       = jQuery(".contact_form #rcont").val();
        var descr       = jQuery(".contact_form #descr").val();
        var success     = jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").data('success');

        jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").empty(); //To empty previous error/success message.
        //checking for blank fields 
        if(fname===''||email===''||bname===''||number===''||package===''||domain===''||logo===''||img===''||rcont===''||descr===''){

            jQuery('div.empty_notice').slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);
        }
        else{
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            jQuery.post("contact_form/contact.php",{ ajax_fname: fname, ajax_email: email, ajax_bname: bname, ajax_number: number, ajax_package: package, ajax_domain: domain, ajax_logo: logo, ajax_img: img, ajax_rcont: rcont, ajax_descr: descr}, function(data) {

                jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").append(data);//Append returned message to message paragraph


                if(jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage span.contact_error").length){
                    jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);     
                }else{
                    jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").append("<span class='contact_success'>"+ success +"</span>");
                    jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").slideDown(500).delay(4000).slideUp(500);
                }

                if(data===""){
                    jQuery("#contact_form")[0].reset();//To reset form fields on success
                }

            });
        }
        return false; 
    });
}

 function reddy_anchor(){

    "use strict";

    jQuery('.anchor_nav').onePageNav();

    var scrollOffset = 70;

    jQuery(".anchor > a").on('click', function(evn){
        evn.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash, {
            gap: { y: -scrollOffset },
            animation:{
                duration: 1500,
                easing: "easeInOutExpo"
            }
        });
        return false;   
    });

}
```

I'd really really appreciate many bits of help here, please!

Here is the form tag:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="" method="POST">
```

And here is the submit button tag:

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-primary btn-wd' name='finish' id="send_message" value='Finish' />
```

Comment: Can you be specific about what the problem is?  There's a lot of code here, and none of us intuitively know what you're expecting it to do.  When you debug this, where specifically is there a problem?  What operation first produces an unexpected result?  What was that result?  What were you expecting?  Why?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried using a more understandable Subject/Topic but somehow StackOverflow is not allowing me to be specific. My issue is, the form is not sending all the form data, it is practically not working!

Comment: And sincerely speaking I do not know where to start debugging from.

Comment: How do you know it is not working?  What happens when you click the button?  Open the dev tools (F12 in chrome) and click the networks tab.  Does anything happen there when you click the button?  Add `console.log('x');` at the beginning of your `reddy_contact_form` function.  When the button is clicked do you see a message in the console?

Comment: On chrome: open inspector> network tab > Now send the form and check the new entry that must says: contact.php, click on that and at the right side you will see response you re getting, the data you're sending and all of that, tell us what is showing

Comment: Nothing is happening when I do all that was instructed.   Here is the link... check yourself and see what i mean.:: http://placmedia.com/packages/starter-package.html

Comment: "the form is not sending all the form data" — Which parts are missing?

Comment: Typo: You used a class selector `.contact_form` but have no elements that are members of that class.

Comment: What's the best possible solution to this and how exactly do I go about it?

Comment: Anyone with a suggestion why this isnt working ??